# How can I programmatically get the node title?

Tags: 8, nodes

A drupal newbie here. I'm looking to build an "issues navigator", a custom block displaying a menu. I'd like to set the "current issue" automatically, from the title of the node that is set as the homepage. How do I do that?'

This does not give me what I want.

```php
$site_frontpage = \Drupal::config('views.view.frontpage');
```

Putting this information into a block will be a separate story.

Comment: The code might give you at best a node ID or a path alias. Load the node from that ID or the path alias using the entity_type.manager service and then you can simply do `$node->getTitle();`.